# How can I get a hight of v-card-title vuetify element?

Tags: vue.js, height, vuetify.js

I have the following code and I would like to get the height of v-card title element?

```
 <v-card-title class="purple lighten-2">
      <v-icon dark size="42" class="mr-4"> fas fa-egg </v-icon>
        <h3 class="white--text font-weight-medium flex-nowrap">
       {{ dishes[dishesIndexList[0]].dish_name }}
     </h3>
 </v-card-title>
```

How can I do it? I tried to add ref="cardTitleHeight" to v-card title and then when the elements are mounted I can get this.$refs and the cardTitleHeight ref I added is listed as part of $refs objects but when I try to get it using this.$refs.cardTitleHeight I get undefined (I need to get this element first to get its hight).
I suppose that it is because v-card-title is an external component.

How is it possible to get v-card-title height? I would be grateful for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question

> when the elements are mounted

The height of this element will be defined after the component has been mounted.

in your script you can try :

```js
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.cardTitleHeight); //.style.height or lineHeight
  },
```

Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted. If you want to wait until the entire view has been rendered, you can use vm.$nextTick inside of mounted.

More about the [mounted life cycle hook](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#mounted).

Comment: Components aren't DOM elements, they don't height/width. Use this `this.$refs.cardTitleHeight.$el.clientHeight`, as is explained in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289580/why-does-the-width-of-my-vue-component-report-undefined